# ViewController is not displayed on screen after pushViewController but it is present in UI-Debugger

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

After getting an AppLink, i am pushing VC on **navigationController**. ViewController does not appear on screen and app is frozen (not crashed). But if i open UI-Debugger, VC is there.

I tried to execute the link on **Main**, it makes the issue rare but is still reproducible sometimes.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    navController?.pluginNavigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: could that be related to async operation? Sometimes using async main thread acts slowly. Did you try synchronous way?

Comment: Yeah i tried, it crashed the app. Problem was something else. I posted the answer below

Answer (score 1):

It can be irrelevant for many but might help someone.

In my case ViewController is implementing `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and I was returning `true` from

```
gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

even if there was 1 ViewController on NavigationStack. This caused app to freeze ( actually next time when i tried to pushViewController with animation, UI got stuck in animation forever).

(In addition to my other checks) Adding following check at the end of method fixed the issue.

```
return navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1
```